# CakePHP onChange event

Tags: html, cakephp, onchange

I have no idea why this `onChange` event is not working. Maybe I got so used to the code that I can't see my mistake. I'd appreciate your help:

```
<td class="cellInput">
  <?php
    $options = array('200'=>'200', '500'=>'500', '1000'=>'1000', '2000'=>'2000', '5000'=>'5000', 'Outro'=>'Outro');
    $attributes = array('legend' => false);

    echo $form->select('capacidade', $options, array(
      'class' => '',
      'label' => '',
      'default' => '200',
      'onchange' => "javascript:checkForOther(this);",
    )); 
  ?>
</td>
```

Comment: You should try and accept answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 2):

As others suggested, place the attributes in the correct parameter position. The other thing i would do is remove the javascript and just have the function name in there like:

From: `'onchange' => "javascript:checkForOther(this);"`

To: `'onchange' => "checkForOther(this)"`

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Putting the attributes as the fourth argument instead of the third:

   ```
   echo $form->select('capacidade', $options, null, 
       array(
           'class'=>''
           ,'label' => ''
           ,'default' => '200'
           ,'onchange' => "javascript:checkForOther(this);"
       )
   );
   ```
2. Does the source of the generated page have the onChange attribute?
3. See the [documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperselect)

Answer (score 0):

According to [CakePHP documentation on select method](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1430/select), the third argument is used to choose which option is selected by default.

You must use the fourth argument to pass HTML attributes to a `select` element:

```
<td class="cellInput">
  <?php
  $options = array('200'=>'200', '500'=>'500', '1000'=>'1000', '2000'=>'2000', '5000'=>'5000', 'Outro'=>'Outro');
  $attributes = array('legend'=>false);
  echo $form->select('capacidade', $options, '200', array('class'=> '', 'label' => '', 'onchange' => "checkForOther(this);")); 
  ?>
</td>
```